# Google Script using if else if not correctly reading variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

I have a function to send emails when a form submits (onformsubmit) and have used If/Else If/Else to determine the correct recipient from one of the form selections. The Value in the form selection is the same as in the script.

At the top I have the below set to pick up the 4th column value. This is working as it is also in the content of the email.

```
var Company = e.values[3];
```

I then have

```
if(Company == 'Company 1 [AA]') {
   MailApp.sendEmail("person1@email.com", subject, emailBody, optAdvancedArgs);
   } 
else if(Company == 'A Company 2 [CC]') {
   MailApp.sendEmail("person2@email.com", subject, emailBody, optAdvancedArgs);
   }
else if(Company == 'Company 3 (CHINA) [EE]' ) {
   MailApp.sendEmail("person3@email.com", subject, emailBody, optAdvancedArgs); 
   }
else {
   MailApp.sendEmail("catch@email.com", subject, emailBody, optAdvancedArgs);
   }
```

My issue is that Company 2 is dropping straight through to the else row and sending to catch@email.com but the rest are working fine (actually have 8 companies in the full code, only 1 has the problem).

Not sure why only having an issue with one of them unless it is the [CC] in the value.

Comment: I'd suggest you add a `console.log(Company)` to your code and see what the value actually is that doesn't match what you are expecting.  Chances are the data isn't exactly what you are comparing for.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00. Although that came up in the log with (what looked as) exactly the same text as I had between the quotes, enough playing with cutting and pasting and adding and removing what look like spaces seemed to resolve it after a several goes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized, and unlikely to help others in future.